# MongoDB: Update field of doc having max of some other field with Lua

Tags: mongodb, lua

I am working on a simple `Lua` script in which I am using this library:

https://github.com/bigplum/lua-resty-mongol

I am trying to update a field of the document having maximum value of some other field in whole collection. Suppose, I have a collection with following docs:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57dfc8fbe0fbcbc219f740d9"),
    "StartTime" : "2016-09-19 11:16:11.000",
    "EndTime": "2016-09-19 11:16:29.000"
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57dfc90de0fbcbc219f740da"),
    "StartTime" : "2016-09-19 11:16:29.000",
    "EndTime": "2016-09-19 11:23:47.000"
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57dfcac3e0fbcbc219f740db"),
    "StartTime" : "2016-09-19 11:23:47.000"
}
```

Now, I want to update / insert `EndTime` field in the latest record (having MAX `StartTime`). Could anybody please let me know how to do it?

Comment: So you want to parse the `StartTime` and then add the `EndTime` based on that?

Comment: Actually, I don't want to parse `StartTime`. It is stored in a format which is lexicographically sortable. All I need to do is update / insert a field in the latest (based on `StartTime`) record in the whole collection. I want to mark the duration when this record was in effect.